# how to render my lorem text in a single block of html

Tags: text, lorem-ipsum

in html my lorem text is too and none of the definition on google is right long i'd like it to be in one block. It's too long

search on google but can't find the proper answer for my question. There's a shortcut to render shorter lorem text?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does https://loremipsum.io/ do what you want? If the text it generates is too long for your needs then please define what "too long" means in your context.